# Colors in main_activity.xml are not refreshed after changing them in colors.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to change `@color/colorPrimary` to any other value but it doesn't change anything in activity_main.xml. Do I also have to change it somewhere else?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary">#33b5e5</color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#7A1EA1</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">#68EFAD</color>
   <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
   <color name="hintColor">#999999</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: how many `colors` files do you have?

Comment: just one colors.xml file

Comment: then just clean your project and rebuild, maybe this helps!

Comment: If cleaning does not work, give us more information. Manifest, Styles, and main_activity xml.

Answer (score 1):

Things to try.

1. Have one color.xml (make sure if you're a library that the calling module doesn't have its own colors.xml).
2. Check the theme, are you using a material theme that uses colorPrimary, et.al.?
3. Try a clean/build, (you can even just do cmd-F9 to MAKE the project, that should ensure the resources are built).
4. How are you using this "color", is the activity using a Material Theme in Android Manifest? What are you expecting to change?

Answer (score 0):

Store all you colours in colors.xml file

```
<resources>
    <!-- App theme colors-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#33b5e5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#7A1EA1</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#68EFAD</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="hintColor">#999999</color>
 </resources>
```

Override the application theme inside styles.xml to change the colors for you application

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="white">@color/white</item>
    <item name="hintColor">@color/hintColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember what I did years ago (might be something along the lines of overriding stuff) but today I tried to change the colors but they didn't. Realized that I changed them at the wrong place. Maybe that helps.

[image]